# Styling of Markdown headings in Apple News components

Tags: markdown, apple-news

I have the following generated ANF document:

```
{
  "version": "0.10.13",
  "identifier": "http://test.domain.com?p=123456",
  "title": "Test Apple News Post",
  "language": "en",
  "layout": {
    "columns": 7,
    "width": 1024
  },
  "components": [
    {
      "text": "Test Apple News Post",
      "role": "title",
      "layout": {
        "margin": {
          "bottom": 30
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "text": "# Heading 1\n\n## HEADING 2\n\n### Heading 3\n\n#### Heading 4\n\n##### Heading 5\n\n###### Heading 6",
      "format": "markdown",
      "role": "body",
      "layout": "bodyLayout"
    }
  ],
  "componentTextStyles": {
    "default": {
      "linkStyle": {
        "textColor": "#DF0033"
      },
      "fontName": "Georgia",
      "fontSize": 12
    },
    "default-title": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 24
    },
    "default-heading": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 24
    },
    "default-heading1": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 24
    },
    "default-heading2": {
      "fontName": "DINCondensed-Bold",
      "fontSize": 18
    },
    "default-heading3": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 22,
      "textColor": "#FF0000"
    },
    "default-heading4": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 20,
      "textColor": "#00FF00"
    },
    "default-heading5": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 18,
      "textColor": "#0000FF"
    },
    "default-heading6": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 16,
      "textColor": "#FF00FF"
    }
  },
  "metadata": {
    "datePublished": "2016-06-06T04:25:34+00:00",
    "dateCreated": "2016-06-06T04:25:34+00:00",
    "dateModified": "2016-06-27T01:05:27+00:00",
    "canonicalURL": "http://test.domain.com?p=123456",
    "thumbnailURL": "http://dummyimage.com/1000x500/000/ffffff&text=Apple+News+Image+1",
    "keywords": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2",
      "tag3"
    ],
    "excerpt": "This is the excerpt text, woo!"
  },
  "componentLayouts": {
    "bodyLayout": {
      "columnStart": 0,
      "columnSpan": 7,
      "margin": {
        "bottom": 15
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that it seems as though font size is never applied for headings 3 through 6, as far as I can tell.

The goal I am seeking to obtain is that `h1` is a large heading in Georgia Bold (with the same style as the `title` component in the document), `h3` - `h6` are gradually smaller versions of the same, and `h2` is a special case that shows a smaller, condensed heading style. I expected this to be fairly simple, but here is my output:

[image: Example Output]

As you can see, there are a few strange things happening here:

1. Clearly the `fontName` property is being picked up from `default-heading2`, as we see the condensed font used there
2. The `textColor` properties I added to ensure that the `default-heading3` - `default-heading6` do anything at all are being picked up and applied.
3. I think that the `fontSize` property is being picked up at least on the `h2`, but can't be sure, maybe that's just the difference in the size of the font itself.

I have also tried removing the entire `default-heading` `componentTextStyle`, on the thought that this might be some kind of weird inheritance thing, but saw no change.

Edit: Also, I've tried reversing entirely the order of the `componentTextStyle`'s on the root element (so that `default-heading6` is defined first, followed by `default-heading5` etc, then after `default-heading1`, finally `default-heading` is defined), and also increased the `version` property of the root element to 1.1.0, based on a warning generated by the preview app. Neither of these changed the output.

Answer (score 0):

OK then, after some investigation, it would appear that there is an undocumented minimum font size for headings in Apple News Format Documents. I was able to surmise this by trial & error modification of the test document in the initial question, eventually leading to the following:

```
{
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "identifier": "http://test.domain.com?p=123456",
  "title": "Test Apple News Post",
  "language": "en",
  "layout": {
    "columns": 7,
    "width": 1024
  },
  "components": [
    {
      "text": "Test Apple News Post",
      "role": "title",
      "layout": {
        "margin": {
          "bottom": 30
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "text": "# Heading 1\n\n## Heading 2\n\n### Heading 3\n\n#### Heading 4\n\n##### Heading 5\n\n###### Heading 6",
      "format": "markdown",
      "role": "body",
      "layout": "bodyLayout"
    }
  ],
  "componentTextStyles": {
    "default": {
      "linkStyle": {
        "textColor": "#DF0033"
      },
      "fontName": "Georgia",
      "fontSize": 12
    },
    "default-title": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 24
    },
    "default-heading": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 24
    },
    "default-heading1": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 20
    },
    "default-heading2": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 21
    },
    "default-heading3": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 22,
      "textColor": "#FF0000"
    },
    "default-heading4": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 23,
      "textColor": "#00FF00"
    },
    "default-heading5": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 24,
      "textColor": "#0000FF"
    },
    "default-heading6": {
      "fontName": "Georgia-Bold",
      "fontSize": 25,
      "textColor": "#FF00FF"
    }
  },
  "metadata": {
    "datePublished": "2016-06-06T04:25:34+00:00",
    "dateCreated": "2016-06-06T04:25:34+00:00",
    "dateModified": "2016-06-27T01:05:27+00:00",
    "canonicalURL": "http://test.domain.com?p=123456",
    "thumbnailURL": "http://dummyimage.com/1000x500/000/ffffff&text=Apple+News+Image+1",
    "keywords": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2",
      "tag3"
    ],
    "excerpt": "This is the excerpt text, woo!"
  },
  "componentLayouts": {
    "bodyLayout": {
      "columnStart": 0,
      "columnSpan": 7,
      "margin": {
        "bottom": 15
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which has the following output:

[image: Heading Font Limit]

As the font only starts to actually increase as of the `h6` element, I would surmise that the heading font size is clamped to a minimum of 24 points.